# During a forkJoin, how can I dispatch an action for each request as well as when they all complete?

Tags: redux, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using **ngrx** in an Angular project. In this example I have an array of requests. I want to dispatch an action after each request but also after all are done.

So far I have something looking like this:

```
Observable.forkJoin(requests).pipe(
  map(() => new actions.requestsSuccessful()),
  catchError(() => of(new actions.requestsFailed()))
);
```

where `requests` is an array of Observables.

The code above works fine, when all requests are done, my `requestsSuccessful()` action is correctly dispatched.

However, I'm implementing a progressbar, which I want to update after **each** request has been made, but I also want to keep the dispatch of the action where **all** requests have been made.

I can't figure out how to dispatch an action after each request while keeping the action when everything is done.

Any ideas?

Comment: is requests an array of obsevables?

Comment: @FanCheung Yes, it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forkJoin` emits only when all Observables complete so it's not useful here. Instead, you can use `concatAll` and `concat`.

This is model example simulating what you want if I understand you correctly.

```
const makeRequest = (v) => of(v)
  .pipe(
    delay(1000), // Simulate delay
    map(response => ({ action: 'WHATEVER', response })), // Map response into action
  );

const requests = [makeRequest(1), makeRequest(2), makeRequest(3)];

from(requests)
  .pipe(
    concatAll(), // Execute Observables in order one at the time
    concat(of({ action: 'ALL_DONE' })), // Append this when all source Observables complete
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo (open console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-zyhuag?file=index.ts

This demo will print the following output:

```
{action: "WHATEVER", response: 1}
{action: "WHATEVER", response: 2}
{action: "WHATEVER", response: 3}
{action: "ALL_DONE"}
```

Btw, in future RxJS versions there will be `endWith` operator that you can use instead of `concat` that makes it more readable. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3679

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it. Maybe this works.

```
let progress=0
Observable.forkJoin(requests.map(e=>e.do(()=>progress++)).pipe(
  map(() => new actions.requestsSuccessful()),
  catchError(() => of(new actions.requestsFailed()))
);
```